# GetQueuedCompletionStatus blocks forever

Tags: sockets, io-completion-ports

I'm writing a server application and I want to use IOCompletion ports, so I wrote a prototype for the server, but I'm facing a problem with GetQueuedCompletionStatus that it never returns(it blocks). Below is my code:

```
bool CreateSocketOverlappedServer()
{
  WSADATA wsaData;
  SOCKADDR_IN sockaddr;

  if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2,),&wsaData)){
    _tprintf(_T("Unable to start up\n"));
    return false;
  }

  SrvSocket = WSASocket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0,NULL,NULL,WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
  if(SrvSocket==INVALID_SOCKET){
    _tprintf(_T("Unable to start socket\n"));
    return false;
  }

  sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sockaddr.sin_port = htons(10000);
  sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  /* now bind the socket */
  if(bind(SrvSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&sockaddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN))==SOCKET_ERROR){
    _tprintf(_T("Unable to bind socket\n"));
    return false;
  }

  if(listen(SrvSocket, 5)==SOCKET_ERROR){
    _tprintf(_T("Error listening\n"));
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```
void WorkerThread(void *arg)
{
   bool bret= false;
   DWORD dwTransferedBytes=0;
   CLIENTS *client;
   PPER_IO_OPERATION_DATA data;

   /* Just sleep for now */
   while(true){
     _tprintf(_T("Entering while\n"));
     bret = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hIocp,&dwTransferedBytes,(PULONG_PTR)&client,(LPOVERLAPPED *) &data,INFINITE);
     if(!bret){
       _tprintf(_T("Unable to process completion port\n"));
     }
   }
   //Sleep(10000); 
}
```

```
void AcceptClientConnections(void *arg)
{
  SOCKET ClientSocket;
  CLIENTS *c;

  _tprintf(_T("Start accepting client connections\n"));


  while(true){  
    ClientSocket = accept(SrvSocket, NULL,NULL);

    if(ClientSocket==INVALID_SOCKET){
      _tprintf(_T("Unable to accept connection\n"));
      continue;
    }

    /* do an association with completion port */
    c = (CLIENTS *)malloc(sizeof(CLIENTS));
    c->sock = ClientSocket;

    /* associate with completion port */
    if(!CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)ClientSocket, hIocp,  (ULONG_PTR)c,0)){
      _tprintf(_T("Unable to associate with completion port\n: %d"),GetLastError());

    }

  }
}
```

Any idea?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the Completion Port correctly, so it has nothing to do, and thus no status to report.  Using a Completion Port with sockets is a two-step process, but you are only doing half of the steps.

Read the following MSDN article for details:

[Windows Sockets 2.0: Write Scalable Winsock Apps Using Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx)

Comment: You might also want to look at my free IOCP client/server framework which shows some slightly more advanced IOCP usage than the MSDN sampled and is, hopefully, a little easier to reuse in your prototype: http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html

Comment: Remy, please clarify it, I create an Iocompletion port,like: hIocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL,0,0,), then associate each accepted socket with that completionport, in my thread pool, GetQueuedCompletionStatus is called, but that thing I'm facing is that it never returns, I mean it blocks forever, I connect to the server via telnet and send any string but GetQueuedCompletionstatus blocks. any suggestion?

Comment: You did not show the initial `CreateIoCompletionPort()` call in the code you posted, nor have you showed any code that uses the sockets once they are connected.  For instance, are you calling `WSARecv()` with an `WSAOVERLAPPED` structure to start reading from an accepted socket via overlapped I/O?  You need to do that in order to trigger `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` for inbound data.

Comment: Sorry coz Ididn't show the call to CreateIocompletionport, but the  call to WSARecv is after GetQueuedCompletionStatus right?

Comment: No, you have to call `WSARecv()` after `accept()` returns a new socket handle for a client.  `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` cannot report status for something that has not been queued yet.  You queue up an overlapped read with `WSARecv()`, then `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` reports when the read actually receives some data from the client, then you issue another `WSARecv()` to queue another read operation, and so on.  Same thing with sending data.  Queue up a send operation with `WSASend()`, then `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` reports when the send has finished.

Comment: I mean, as a client connect to the server and send some string on the socket, isn't it queued on the completion port?

Comment: No, it is not. Nothing is queued untill you queue it up yourself in your code. You decide when to read and when to write. Some servers don't read right away, they write a greeting first.  So queuing up a read cannot be automated by the API because it might not be the correct thing to do in all situations. In your case, you do want to read right away, so just call `WSARecv()` after `accept()` returns a new socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The markup in the MSDN link is totally broken. Do you know where a scanned copy of that article is available?

Answer (score 1):

ONe possibility: Check if you have associated the listener socket with the completion port (made this mistake myself). If you haven't the GetQueuedCompletionStatus() will block forever.