# GetQueuedCompletionStatus blocking indefinitely on UDP socket

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock

I'm attempting to create a UDP client/server class that relies on IO completion ports using Winsock, but I haven't been able to get the GetQueuedCompletionStatus() function to return when new data is available. This is likely due to some misunderstanding on my part, but examples/documentation on IOCP with UDP instead of TCP are few and far between.

Here's the relevant bits of my server class, with error checking removed for brevity:

```
Server::Server()
{
    m_iocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
}

void Server::StartReceiving()
{
    StopReceiving();

    m_iocp = CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)m_receiveSocket, m_iocp, (DWORD)this, 0);

    //WSAEVENT event = WSACreateEvent();
    //WSAEventSelect(m_receiveSocket, event, FD_ACCEPT | FD_CLOSE);

    // Start up worker thread for receiving data
    m_receiveThread.reset(new std::thread(&Server::ReceiveWorkerThread, this));
}

void Server::Host(const std::string& port)
{
    if (!m_initialized)
        Initialize();

    addrinfo hints = {};
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    const char* portStr = port.empty() ? kDefaultPort.c_str() : port.c_str();
    int result;
    AddressInfo addressInfo = AddressInfo::Create(nullptr, portStr, &hints, result); // Calls getaddrinfo()

    m_receiveSocket = WSASocket(addressInfo.GetFamily(), addressInfo.GetSocketType(), addressInfo.GetProtocol(), nullptr, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);

    // Bind receiving socket
    result = bind(m_receiveSocket, addressInfo.GetSocketAddress(), addressInfo.GetAddressLength());

    StartReceiving();
}

void Server::ReceiveWorkerThread()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN senderAddr;
    int senderAddrSize = sizeof(senderAddr);
    DWORD bytesTransferred = 0;
    OVERLAPPED* pOverlapped = nullptr;
    WSABUF wsaBuf = { (ULONG)m_buffer.GetWriteBufferSize(), m_buffer.GetWriteBufferPointer() };

    DWORD flags = 0;
    DWORD bytesReceived;
    int result = WSARecvFrom(m_receiveSocket, &wsaBuf, 1, &bytesReceived, &flags, (sockaddr*)&senderAddr, &senderAddrSize, pOverlapped, nullptr);

    // Process packets until signaled to exit
    while (true)
    {
        DWORD context = 0;
        BOOL success = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
            m_iocp,
            &bytesTransferred,
            &context,
            &pOverlapped,
            INFINITE);

        wsaBuf.len = (ULONG)m_buffer.GetWriteBufferSize();
        wsaBuf.buf = m_buffer.GetWriteBufferPointer();
        flags = 0;

        result = WSARecvFrom(m_receiveSocket, &wsaBuf, 1, &bytesReceived, &flags, (sockaddr*)&senderAddr, &senderAddrSize, pOverlapped, nullptr);

        // Code to process packet would go here

        if (m_exiting.load() == true)
            break; // Kill worker thread
    }
}
```

When my client sends data to the server, the first WSARecvFrom picks up the data correctly but the server blocks on the call to GetQueuedCompletionStatus and never returns, even if more datagrams are sent. I've also tried putting the socket into non-blocking mode with WSAEventSelect (code for that is commented above), but it made no difference.

From reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813549/getqueuedcompletionstatus-blocks-forever) similar post it sounds like there needs to be at least one read on the socket to trigger IOCP, which is why I added the first call to WSARecvFrom outside the main loop. Hopefully I'm correct in assuming that the client code is irrelevant if the server receives the data without IOCP, so I haven't posted it.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the result code from `WSARecvFrom` and call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` only if the return code is `ERROR_IO_PENDING`- if it is not either the operation completed without blocking and you have the data, or there was an error, but in any of these cases it was not posted to the I/O completion port and thus it will never be picked up by `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`and the call will block.

And you should not do this in one thread. The common approach is to have a thread that only polls the I/O completion port and calls some callbacks on context objects to notify about incoming/outgoing data, and the sending receiving calls are called wherever needed.

Comment: Thanks. If I'm understanding this correctly, I should have multiple threads (likely based on the number of processors) calling GetQueuedCompletionStatus in a loop? Would these threads also call WSARecvFrom, or would that be handled by a different worker procedure?

Comment: Yes, use a pool of threads that loop on GetQueuedCompletionStatus(). When you start your server, call WSARecvFrom() to get things rolling. When any of the worker threads receives a completed packet, process the data as needed and then call WSARecvFrom() to queue the next packet.

Comment: @NickBlakely well if your case is trivial you may as well be good off with the example you have. What I'm saying is, that the common approach is to have some kind of class/struct that represents a single connection, and use that either in the overlapped structure or as the completion key (depends on the I/O flow) so then you can call lets say a function `OnBytesWritten`/`OnBytesRead` for that object when `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` returns. These methods then will either continue reading/writing or do smth else. That way you have the logic seperate from the mechanism that does the I/O.

Comment: Thanks Rudolfs Bundulis and @RemyLebeau. Working perfectly now with your help.